# Performance profiling a KEXT

Tags: macos, performance-testing, kernel-module, kernel-extension

How to measure performance impact of a kext in OS X in terms of CPU, memory or thread usage during some user defined activities ? Any particular method tool that can be use from user land ? OR any approach/method that can be considered?

Comment: To those trying to close this question: care to justify your "off-topic" and "too-broad" opinions? This is not a subject that is covered in any depth anywhere prominent, so a fairly broad question seems valid.

Answer (score 4):

You've essentially got 2 options:

1. Instrumenting your kext with time measurements. Take stamps before and after the operation you're trying to measure using `mach_absolute_time()`, convert to a human-readable unit using `absolutetime_to_nanoseconds()` and take the difference, then collect that information somewhere in your kext where it can be extracted from userspace.
2. Sampling kernel stacks using dtrace (`iprofiler -kernelstacks -timeprofiler` from the command line, or using Instruments.app)

Personally, I've had a lot more success with the former method, although it's definitely more work. Most kext code runs so briefly that a sampling profiler barely catches any instances of it executing, unless you reduce the sampling interval so far that measurements start interfering with the system, or your kext is seriously slow. It's pretty easy to do though, so it's often a valid sanity check.

You can also get your compiler to instrument your code with counters (`-fprofile-arcs`), which in theory will allow you to combine the sampling statistics with the branch counters to determine the runtime of each branch. Extracting this data is a pain though ([my code](https://github.com/pmj/kext-cov) may help) and again, the statistical noise has made this useless for me in practice.

The explicit method also allows you to measure asynchronous operations, etc., but of course also comes with some intrinsic overhead. Accumulating the data safely is also a little tricky. (I use atomic operations, but you could use spinlocks too. Don't forget to not just measure means but also standard deviation, and minimum/maximum times.) And extracting the data can be a pain because you have to add a userspace interface to your kext for it. But it's definitely worth it!

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, I will try the options.

Comment: Is it not possible to make the os_signpost work in kext? It would be nice to use Instruments.